# Why cant cast from pointer to reference to pointer in template function

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have error in compile time

```
INLINE template<typename T> T *&Animation::GetKey(int subAnim, int node, int frameInSubAnim)
{
    const int keyIndex = GetKeyIndex(subAnim, node, frameInSubAnim);
    return static_cast<T*>(m_Keys[keyIndex]);
}
```

With following error

```
d:\before_me\motion\pipeline\animation\AnimationData.inl(98): 
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'Motion::Animation::Key *' to 'Motion::Animation::Key *&'
```

and how i can workaround it?

Comment: A reference is always to some object. Which object do you want to reference?

Comment: @n.m., i can get reference to int, why i cant get it to pointer to int

Comment: Let's discuss code that we both can see. I only see an attempt to reference some temporary pointer. This cannot possibly work. Perhaps you wanted to reference some other, non-temporary pointer. Which one?

Comment: Why temporary? its a pointer stored in array. Ok, i will test

Comment: No, `m_Keys[keyIndex]` is a pointer stored in an array, `static_cast<T*>(m_Keys[keyIndex])` is a pointer of a different type, not stored anywhere.

Comment: @Yola: even ignoring C++ rules for a moment, purely from the POV of the implementation, the casted pointer may be *bitwise different* from the original pointer (as in case of multiple inheritance), thus it must be a copy (temporary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this captures what you want and provides a *hideous* workaround

```
void* m_keys[] = { 0, 0, 0 };

template<typename T>
T*& foo(const int index)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<T**>(&m_keys[index]);
}

int main()
{
 foo<int>(0) = new int();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is telling you that the `static_cast<T*>(...)` yields a temporary (*rvalue*) and that cannot be bound by a non-const reference (return type is `T*&`). Note that even it it would bind to `T*const&` you don't really want that.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but consider returning `T*` (drop the reference).

Comment: thanks, i wanna change/initialize that pointer. not change something in location pointed by that pointer. may be solution is to return T**, but its not very nice.

Comment: @Yola: What is the type of `m_Keys`? If that type is `T**` or `T *[N]` then you don't *need* the cast, if it is anything other than that you don't **want** the cast.

Comment: @Yola: pointers to what type? The important bit is the exact type of the pointers stored.